# Hexahedral mathematical object.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

According to wikipedia a matrix (plural matrices) is a rectangular array or table of numbers, symbols, or expressions, arranged in rows and columns.
Is there any mathematical object which is hexahedral (like cubic) array of numbers?

Comment: Yes, in various ways. See for example for a [hexagonal grid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295539/alignment-of-rotated-hexagonal-grid) for $\Bbb Z[\omega]$, or [Centered hexagon of integers](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjt5v7R7Mf2AhVSiqQKHVZCAy4QFnoECAYQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.671.6614%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AOvVaw1NnrcfSP5LQKuO5IE4v5ih) for sequences, just to name two possibilities. I suppose the question is too broad right now.

Comment: In combinatorics, hexagonal arrays are very common, too. See for example [Honeycomb Arrays](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi79r6_7cf2AhUFDuwKHZSVAKYQFnoECAgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.combinatorics.org%2Fojs%2Findex.php%2Feljc%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2Fv17i1r172%2Fpdf%2F&usg=AOvVaw3OSSLVg8_WnXUOAwhXEg1r).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I didn't mean hexagon. I mean hexahedral. It is a polyhedron that has six faces like a cubic.

Comment: So you also mean then not matrices, but "hypermatrices" like cubes? Because you compared with $2$-dimensional square arryas, called matrices. Anyway, these are used also in different contexts. You need to specify what exactly you want.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I mean there is a rectangular array of numbers which called matrix. What about a cubic array of numbers, is there anything like taht in mathematics?

Comment: Yes, as I said, they are popular in combinatorics, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186738/is-it-possible-to-exist-a-three-dimensional-matrix). Your question has been asked in several different variations. See for example also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338933/are-there-such-things-as-3-dimensional-and-higher-analogues-of-matrices-and-i) and others.